# Avicii - Stories | Uncredited vocals?

Tags: electronic-music

Avicii is well known for not giving credit to the artists that sing in his songs.

I am currently looking for the singers featured in his new album: **Stories**.

Here's the tracklist of the album; I'm attaching the singers' names I've been able to find out:

1. Waiting For Love (ft. Simon Aldred)
2. **Talk To Myself**
3. **Touch Me**
4. Ten More Days (ft. Zak Abel)
5. For A Better Day (ft. Alex Ebert)
6. Broken Arrows (ft. Zac Brown)
7. **True Believer**
8. **City Lights**
9. Pure Grinding (ft. Kristoffer Fogelmark & Earl St. Clair)
10. **Sunset Jesus**
11. **Can't Catch Me**
12. **Somewhere In Stockholm**
13. **Trouble**
14. Gonna Love Ya (ft. Sandro Cavazza)
15. The Days (ft. Robbie Williams)
16. The Nights (ft. Nicholas "RAS" Furlong)

Could you help me find out the remaining singers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I could gather:

1. Waiting For Love (feat. Simon Aldred)
2. Talk To Myself (feat. Sterling Fox)
3. Touch Me (feat. Audra Mae)
4. Ten More Days (feat. Zak Abel)
5. For a Better Day (feat. Alex Ebert)
6. Broken Arrows (feat. Zac Brown)
7. True Believer (feat. Chris Martin)
8. City Lights (feat. Noonie Bao)
9. Pure Grinding (feat. Earl St. Clair & Kristoffer Fogelmark)
10. Sunset Jesus (feat. Gavin DeGraw)
11. Can't Catch Me (feat. Matisyahu & Wyclef Jean)
12. Somewhere In Stockholm (feat. Daniel Adams-Ray)
13. Trouble (feat. Wayne Hector)
14. Gonna Love Ya (feat. Alessandro Cavazza)
15. The Days (feat. Robbie Williams)
16. The Nights (feat. Nicholas "RAS" Furlong)

Jonas Wallin also provides vocals, I assume in the songs he co-wrote ("City Lights" and "Somewhere in Stockholm") but I don't think it's worth crediting him as, if he did, they're surely background vocals. Avicii also sings in at least one song ("True Believer").

I hope this was of any help; it really bothers me that the singers aren't credited on the album.

Comment: That was great man, thanks a lot!
Yeah, it bothers me too that Avicii doesn't credit singers.. And I certainly don't understand why he does that...